# How to add Maven project Build in JBoss through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am using Eclipse Helios and JBoss 4.2.0.

I have built a maven project in eclipse. A war file is getting generated in the target as a maven build.

Also I have configured the Jboss server through eclipse. When I right click on JBoss server in eclipse and say "Add or Remove". it is giving me the following message "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server".

Please help me running maven build on JBoss server. So that I can debug my code

Comment: Would running the JBoss outside eclipse and deploying the war there be an option? You could then debug through a remote connection (we do that a lot).

Comment: @Thomas Would you please explain this a bit.

Comment: Hi SAM, could you find any solution to that problem? If yes, it will be great to share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (although technically not an answer to your question) would be to use the JBoss outside eclipse (which is the option I'd prefer anyways).

I assume you know how to set up a JBoss instance and deploy a war to it, so I'll only explain the debugging procedure.

In the JBoss' run.bat/run.conf there's a debugging line that's commented by default (I don't know the exact contents but you should be able to find it). Remove the comment to activate that line and you're almost good to go. Within that debug config there an option for the port to listen to, which normally is port 8787, as well as a `suspend` option, which by default it set to `y`. That second option will cause the JBoss to wait for the debugger on startup when set to `y`, thus set that to `n`.

When the JBoss is running you can attach the Eclipse debugger by creating a "remote Java application" configuration and attach to the port the server listens to (8787 by default).

Comment: Where is the option to create the "remote java application" in eclipse? I enabled remote debuging on Jboss but stuck in how to use it in eclipse.

Comment: @ziggy It's under "Debug Configurations..."->"Remote Java Application". There you create a new configuration, use the standard connection type and the port you enabled in the JBoss config (by default it should be port 8787)

Answer (score 3):

Try right clicking on the project on the navigator and click on "Make Deployable" or "Mark as Deployable". Then try adding to the server. If it doesn't work then you can do Laures said you can check the maven jboss plugin here [Maven Jboss plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Would you please tell me how to use this in POM.xml

Comment: How to use the plugin is given in the provided link. Here is the summary :- in your <build> section define the <plugin> from the provided link. Then from your project root folder (where you pom.xml is) you can run 'mvn jboss:hard-deploy' and 'mvn jboss:hard-undeploy' if you want the plugin to copy the war to the server's deploy folder. You can go through the provided link and here is more info [http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)

Answer (score 1):

there is a maven-jboss plugin. its part of the jboss-tools for eclipse.
worked for me in several projects.

Answer (score 0):

You might have created normal maven project.
Create a project of archetypy webapp-jee5 .

Web projects can be added from eclipse to servers.